# Alfresco fails to create video thumbnail

Tags: ffmpeg, alfresco

As error log says : `Empty input file ...` It turned out that the source image for `ImageMagick` is zero sized. (`/data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_source_8718262212685093199.jpg`). When I manually replace the source image to normal image and execute the command again, there's no error.

`command:    /data/was/alfresco/common/bin/convert /data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_source_8718262212685093199.jpg[0] -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" -strip -quiet /data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_target_7652060684136589026.png`

So I think the source image is maybe made by `FFMPEG` by capturing some frame of the video.
And the `FFMPEG` somehow failed to do it. Not sure my guess is right...

But my `FFMPEG` works good as `ffmpeg -version` shows proper version info. And `FFMPEG` is run by `root` and the Alfresco daemon instance is run by `root`. It seems that there's nothing wrong.

Please review it. Here's the whole Alfresco-share log :

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 09160037 Content conversion failed:
   reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store:///data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ComplextTransformer_intermediate_mp4_262176879279399174.jpg, mimetype=image/jpeg, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
   writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store:///data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/FailoverTransformer_intermediate_ComplexContentTransformer_5223852355212570043.png, mimetype=image/png, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
   options: {use=doclib, contentReaderNodeRef=null, contentWriterNodeRef=null, sourceContentProperty=null, imageAutoOrient=true, targetContentProperty=null, commandOptions=, imageResizeOptions=ImageResizeOptions [width=100, height=100, maintainAspectRatio=true, percentResize=false, resizeToThumbnail=false, allowEnlargement=false], includeEmbedded=null}
   limits: {timeoutMs=120000, pageLimit=1}
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:350)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ComplexContentTransformer.transformInternal(ComplexContentTransformer.java:492)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:272)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 09160036 Failed to perform ImageMagick transformation:
Execution result:
   os:         Linux
   command:    /data/was/alfresco/common/bin/convert /data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_source_8718262212685093199.jpg[0] -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" -strip -quiet /data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_target_7652060684136589026.png
   succeeded:  false
   exit code:  1
   out:
   err:        .convert.bin: Empty input file `/data/was/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_source_8718262212685093199.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/331.
.convert.bin: NoImageForProperty "%w" @ warning/property
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.magick.ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.transformInternal(ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.java:205)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.magick.AbstractImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.transform(AbstractImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.java:284)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:79)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.transform(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer.transformInternal(ProxyContentTransformer.java:107)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:272)
        ... 34 more
```

In alfresco-global.properties : `ffmpeg.exe=/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg`

*** Update** As Robert suggested, TransFormer log level changed to debug.
But the log is too long to paste here. There's 30,000 characters limit of body in SO which github doesn't have.
So please refer to github issue, I pasted the log there.
https://github.com/Alfresco/share/issues/127

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is already the consequential error.
Previews of videos are created by so called complex transformers (pipeline of transformers). Please enable logging for the transformer and try again to find out the initial problem.

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.TransformerDebug=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.content.transform=DEBUG
```

Some sources which may help you:

- [Content Transformation Debug](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-hub/content-transformation-debug/ba-p/289284)
- [Content Transformers (and Renditions)](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-content-transformer.html)

An easy way to test transformers would be to install [ootbee-support-tools](https://github.com/OrderOfTheBee/ootbee-support-tools) and use [Test-Transform](https://github.com/OrderOfTheBee/ootbee-support-tools/wiki/Test-Transform)

Comment: As you suggested, TransFormer log level changed to debug.
But the log is too long to paste here. There's 30,000 characters limit of body in SO which github doesn't have.
So please refer to github issue, I pasted the log there. 
https://github.com/Alfresco/share/issues/127 Really appreciate your help and concern.

Comment: It looks like your `command:    sh -c "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -ss 10 -i ...` produces an empty image file. Try the conversion step manually in the command line as stated in the log. I guess you either have videos not supported by your ffmpeg installation or your lib path in alfresco properties do not fit.
Maybe it is also an wrong environment the command is executed by Alfresco so you could set:
`log4j.logger.org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec=debug` or to see the full environment set during execution: `log4j.logger.org.alfresco.util.exec=trace`

Comment: I have tried another `mp4` files and some of them successfully created the thumbnail! But I don't get what the differences between the files. Maybe my `ffmpeg` misses some codecs? or need to adjust the start time?(the `-ss` flag). Could you direct me which Alfresco config file has the the start time option? I guess 10(sec) is too big. I need it changed to 1 or 2.